# test timers in react, sinon or jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, timer, jestjs, sinon

I have a funtion `checkIdleTime`, being set to be called periodically.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var idleCheck = setInterval(this.checkIdleTime.bind(this), authTimeoutSeconds * 1000);
    this.setState({idleCheck: idleCheck});

    document.onkeypress = this.setActive;
}
```

I want to use the fake timer for test, but can't figure out how, tried `sinon` 
and `jest`.

```
beforeEach(() => {   
    checkIdleTime = jest.spyOn(PureMain.prototype, 'checkIdleTime');
    wrapper = shallow(
        <PureMain/>
    );

    jest.useFakeTimers();
    //clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();  
});

it('should check the idle time after [authTimeoutSeconds] seconds of inactivity', () => {

    wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();

    var idleCheck_timeout = wrapper.instance().state.idleCheck;
    expect(idleCheck_timeout).not.toEqual(null);
    expect(idleCheck_timeout._idleTimeout).toBe(authTimeoutSeconds * 1000);
    jest.runAllTimers();
    //clock.tick(authTimeoutSeconds * 1000 * 2);
    expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);//not work
    expect(checkIdleTime).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);//not work
})
```

Got error:

> Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

I tried to follow those examples

https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/fake-timers/

---

Can't find a good example on how to spy on `setInterval`

```
expect(setInterval.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

> Cannot read property 'calls' of undefined

```
expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

> value must be a mock function or spy.

Comment: What version of `sinon` are you using?

Comment: i think it is sinon 4.1.2

Comment: Also, what is the error that you get when using `sinon`?

Comment: I got the same error message for both. is there anything wrong with the spy?

Comment: I think so. Can you confirm that both `expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` and `expect(checkIdleTime).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` are not working, separately? Like, comment out the first one and try and then comment out the second line and try.

Comment: doesn't work seporately, besides I don't expect setInterval to work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the spy should be declared as:

```
setTimeout_spy = jest.spyOn(window, 'setTimeout');
```